# MVC site works in VS but null exception in IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nullreferenceexception

I've been working on a MVC 4 application which works when I run it on visual studio, however when i deploy it to IIS 7 i get a null reference exception. The error occurs immediately, as soon as the page tries to load.

I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255292/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-ie-issue) but it had no effect.

The stack trace shows:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      MedicalPractitionerPartnership.Controllers.HomeController.Index() +856
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +78
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +241
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +38
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +11
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +138
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +111
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +452
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +37
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Comment: what is the iispool you are using?

Comment: See [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). Apply logging or perform remote debugging to find out what variable or property is null.

Comment: the iispool is called MPP. I know what a nullReferenceexception is but why does it only happen on iis, why is VS running the application without getting an exception?